# How would I go about creating a new MySQL table with the results of "myisam_ftdump -c"?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm using `myisam_ftdump -c` to dump the occurrences of words in my fulltext column. What's the simplest way to insert that information into a new MySQL table?

Thanks for any help, it's appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dump the results > to a file and use a [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) query to import the contents back into your new table.

Note:

> For security reasons, when reading text files located on the server, the files must either reside in the database directory or be readable by all. Also, to use LOAD DATA INFILE on server files, you must have the FILE privilege.